# how to proxy socket.io to server with webpack-dev-server

Tags: node.js, socket.io, create-react-app, http-proxy-middleware

- Node：v12.19.0
- Egg.js：v2.27.0
- create-react-app: v4.0.0
- http-proxy-middleware: v1.0.6
- socket.io-client: v2.3.1

#### react client:

```js
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io({
  transports: ['websocket']
});
socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('socket.io client connected!');
});
```

#### setupProxy.js

```js
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.use(
    '/socket.io',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://127.0.0.1:7001',
      changeOrigin: true,
      ws: true
    })
  );
};
```

code above not work.

The websocket works well, if the client code is following:

```js
const socket = io('http://127.0.0.1:7001', {
  transports: ['websocket']
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but this work for me. (no need to use `transports` options)

#### setupProxy.js

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.use(
    '/socket.io',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'ws://127.0.0.1:7001',
      changeOrigin: true
    })
  );
};
```